# Filter two arrays with conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two array who share common column .I want to apply a filter on array `filters` and get `n_fnc`  where all stat in second array `conditions` equal to act.

If it has different stats even if one is "act" it should not be selected

```
filters [{n_fnc: 2343, name: "jack"} ,{n_fnc:2500 , name:"daniel"},{n_fnc:3000 , name:"trump"}]

Conditions [{id :1 ,n_fnc: 2343, stat:"do"},
            {id:2, n_fnc: 2343, stat:"act"},
            {id:3, n_fnc: 2343, stat:"plan"},
            {id:10, n_fnc: 2500, stat:"act"},
            {id:18, n_fnc: 2500, stat:"act"},
            {id:20, n_fnc: 3000, stat:"act"}
]


result = [2500,3000]
```

I tried with the every and filter function but it doesn't return anything.

```
  let result = this.filters.filter(o =>
  this.conditions.filter(({n_fnc}) => n_fnc === o.n_fnc).every(({stat}) => stat=== 'act'));
```

Comment: because 2343 have other  stat different to act

Comment: check your question you write state act for conditions[1] with id=2

Comment: @MehranBeiglou I updated the question check it now

Comment: Your code is fine, please share the code where you declare those conditions and filters variable and the function that deal with the filtering . I believe this is a problem relating to the function 's context

Comment: @HamzaNouri thanks for your update, i think my answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works, but if you need `result` to be array of number, you need to use `map`:

```js
class test {
    filters = [{ n_fnc: 2343, name: "jack" }, { n_fnc: 2500, name: "daniel" }, { n_fnc: 3000, name: "trump" }]

    conditions = [{ id: 1, n_fnc: 2343, stat: "do" },
    { id: 2, n_fnc: 2343, stat: "act" },
    { id: 3, n_fnc: 2343, stat: "plan" },
    { id: 10, n_fnc: 2500, stat: "act" },
    { id: 18, n_fnc: 2500, stat: "act" },
    { id: 20, n_fnc: 3000, stat: "act" }
    ]

    getResult() {
        let result = this.filters
            .filter(o =>
                this.conditions
                    .filter(({ n_fnc }) => n_fnc === o.n_fnc)
                    .every(({ stat }) => stat === 'act')
            )
            .map(r => r.n_fnc);
    }
}

const t = new test();
console.log(t.getResult());
```

Comment: this just return for me all n_fnc , it s like the filter doesn"t apply on filters array

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```js
const r = filters.filter(o => {
    const i = Conditions.findIndex(c => c.n_fnc === o.n_fnc);
    if(i > -1) {
        if(Conditions[i].stat === 'act') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
.map(o => o.n_fnc)

console.log(r); // [ 2500, 3000 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one i think will help you

```js
const filters = [
  { n_fnc: 2343, name: "jack" },
  { n_fnc: 2500, name: "daniel" },
  { n_fnc: 3000, name: "trump" },
];
conditions = [
  { id: 1, n_fnc: 2343, stat: "do" },
  { id: 2, n_fnc: 2343, stat: "act" },
  { id: 3, n_fnc: 2343, stat: "plan" },
  { id: 10, n_fnc: 2500, stat: "act" },
  { id: 18, n_fnc: 2500, stat: "act" },
  { id: 20, n_fnc: 3000, stat: "act" },
];
const result = []
filters.forEach((filter) => {
  if (
    !conditions
      .filter((condition) => condition.n_fnc == filter.n_fnc)
      .some((nc) => nc.stat != "act")
  ) {
    result.push(filter.n_fnc);
  }
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't know why in my code result return null ,I used it in my constructor

Comment: can i ask you share your code in stackblitz or stuff to help you?